# Resolve "Id must be a String" in CloudFormation Template error

Tags: aws-cloudformation

The following is in the Resources Section of my CloudFormation Template:

```
  myAlbTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200,302
      Name: myWebServer
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 80
      Targets:
        - Id: Fn::ImportValue: myVPC-myWebServer1
          Port: 80
        - Id: Fn::ImportValue: myVPC-myWebServer2
          Port: 80
      TargetType: instance
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: myVPC
```

When I load the Template I get an error indicating "Id must be a String" for Targets.

Per another thread I read, I've wrapped the value in quotes, and also tried to use `!Sub`, but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I've been through the Docs, but I'm obviously missing something (probably basic).

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: What exactly is `myVPC-myWebServer1`? You haven't provided its definition. Also what it the full error message.

Comment: Thanks for the question / comment. "myVPC-myWebServer1" is an EC2 Instance in the VPC which was created using a different CloudFormation Template (hence the Fn::ImportValue). The exact error message was "Id must be a String" - it wasn't very helpful / descriptive. However, I was able to resolve this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. It was an alignment / formatting issue. I'll post the proper format here for anyone that might be interested.

```
      Targets:
        - Id: 
            Fn::ImportValue: 
             !Sub 'myVPC-myWebServer1'
          Port: 80
        - Id: 
            Fn::ImportValue:
             !Sub 'myVPC-myWebServer2'
          Port: 80
```